# Unable to work with React Native Async Storage

Tags: react-native

I am having difficulty working with react native async storage.
Most of the time my code jumps off the current execution and goes to the next line without getting the results from the current line. I am getting errors most of the time.

I tried this example-

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AsyncStorage,
  PickerIOS,
  Text,
  View
} = React;
var PickerItemIOS = PickerIOS.Item;

var STORAGE_KEY = '@AsyncStorageExample:key';
var COLORS = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue'];

var BasicStorageExample = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done();
  },

  async _loadInitialState() {
    try {
      var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
      if (value !== null){
        this.setState({selectedValue: value});
        this._appendMessage('Recovered selection from disk: ' + value);
      } else {
        this._appendMessage('Initialized with no selection on disk.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      this._appendMessage('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selectedValue: COLORS[0],
      messages: [],
    };
  },

  render() {
    var color = this.state.selectedValue;
    return (
      <View>
        <PickerIOS
          selectedValue={color}
          onValueChange={this._onValueChange}>
          {COLORS.map((value) => (
            <PickerItemIOS
              key={value}
              value={value}
              label={value}
            />
          ))}
        </PickerIOS>
        <Text>
          {'Selected: '}
          <Text style={{color}}>
            {this.state.selectedValue}
          </Text>
        </Text>
        <Text>{' '}</Text>
        <Text onPress={this._removeStorage}>
          Press here to remove from storage.
        </Text>
        <Text>{' '}</Text>
        <Text>Messages:</Text>
        {this.state.messages.map((m) => <Text key={m}>{m}</Text>)}
      </View>
    );
  },

  async _onValueChange(selectedValue) {
    this.setState({selectedValue});
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, selectedValue);
      this._appendMessage('Saved selection to disk: ' + selectedValue);
    } catch (error) {
      this._appendMessage('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  },

  async _removeStorage() {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
      this._appendMessage('Selection removed from disk.');
    } catch (error) {
      this._appendMessage('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  },

  _appendMessage(message) {
    this.setState({messages: this.state.messages.concat(message)});
  },
});

exports.title = 'AsyncStorage';
exports.description = 'Asynchronous local disk storage.';
exports.examples = [
  {
    title: 'Basics - getItem, setItem, removeItem',
    render(): ReactElement { return <BasicStorageExample />; }
  },
];
```

This works. But, my functions doesn't work as expected. I am getting `undefined`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the errors you are getting? Also, at what point in the code you are getting these errors?

Comment: I am not getting any error. The functions order are not executing like how I want to. Lokesh answer seems to be a solution for me. that git repo looks so simple to implement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading your question, first thing I felt is "maybe" you are new to ES7, specifically `async-await`. Please read about [async-await](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html) functions in ES7 which is about to be realeased later this year(2016).

Your functions have to be `async` in nature. Put the keyword before the function. And `await` has to be used where you make a call to the function.

Specifically I suggest you use [react-native-store](https://github.com/thewei/react-native-store/) repo for your development. React Native guys have told to use this and other implementations clearly agreeing `AsyncStorage` is a bit complex to work with.

Comment: WoW! that looks like a great implementation of react native store. example is so simple. i will give it a try. and thanks for telling me about async await.

Answer (score 21):

For others who still couldn't fix this issue: import AsyncStorage from react-native instead of React.

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: This should be at the top. Its not in the docs and the errors u get are non-descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is using `AsyncStorage.multiSet([])`, make sure that none of your values is `null` or `undefined`. Otherwise, it won't work and and won't set value to the valid key-value pairs.